# Is the algorithm for choosing Pro Tempore moderators on new sites fair?

Tags: discussion, moderation, pro-tem-moderators

I come from Startups SE, a fairly new site which just got out of private beta about a month ago. My use of the site has dwindled in the last few weeks, as I took some personal effect to an interesting choice of moderators which I and many others found surprising.

Forgive me for sounding selfish - clearly I am. But I just want to make this clear. The post given on startups meta, which I'm sure is referenced all over, **includes the following block as criteria for being selected for a Pro Tempore moderator position:**

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent
>   participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building
>   activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their
>   fellow community members in everything they write. Exhibit those
>   intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.
>
> Bonus points
> for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e.
>   interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the
>   site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote
>   their community. Candidates will be contacted and three of them will
>   be selected to act as provisional Moderators until the community holds
>   formal elections after the Beta period.
>
> Besides the normal abilities
> of a Moderator, they will:
>
> - Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work
>   through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> - Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (domain names,
>   design issues, the [help center], etc.).
> - Rally community support and
>   drive the mission of getting publicity for the site. Essentially, they
>   will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for anything we can do to
>   help their sites succeed!

First off - wow. This sounds amazing.

When I first read this meta post, I was so excited. I worked as hard as I could to place as best I could in the process. Just a few notes to consider here:

- Out of the 4 nominated persons, I tied for the second most community votes with 6 votes, one of them being a moderator from a different network (7-6-6-2 - having upvoted all other three candidates)
- I led the site with more reputation than the second and third combined (2300 vs 1400 and 800). I was second most active in edits and the most active in reviews. I logged on around 50 times every day (yeah I'm obsessed but that's kind of my point).
- I was the most active member in the chat and provided knowledgeable answers in short amounts of time to those seeking information (this was undisputed among anyone from startups)
- I followed and asked questions on Area 51, having been part of the earliest phase to get startups initiated.

**So my biggest question - what did I do *wrong?***

I've heard from many people on the network that it is because my reputation on Stack Overflow is low, or that I didn't have high reputation on another one of the networks.

*If this is the case,* I have three words for this community: *shame on you!* If one communicates on a network where he or she has to be adept in two industries to moderate the one he or she excels in, what kind of *ill representation is this of the real specialized world we live in?*

A few points - telling me that "you wouldn't like being a moderator" or "if you're that active, the community needs you doing other things than being a moderator" seem totally moot and invalid to me.

Yes - I'm selfish, but I'm concerned I was misled and I would like any future try-hards like myself to *better know what to expect* if they want to become a pro-temp moderator.

I know it's just a Stack Exchange site but I felt at home there, and honestly I did take it personally. I know I won't get any condolences and I don't need them - I just don't want anyone else to experience the pain I did.

Comment: Seeing the position of a moderator as a "prize for the winning" automatically disqualifies you in my eyes (this is my personal opinion, not as a Stack Exchange employee).

Comment: @Oded Isn't that beside the point?

Comment: Of course not. What you listed is the minimum required for _consideration_ for a pro tem position. Attitude and interactions weigh in just as much. The position is one that can considerably effect the direction of the site (or even its future) - it is about getting considered, not about "winning it".

Comment: My point - there are some requirements that you listed above, that the community team takes into consideration when selecting pro-tempore moderators. There isn't an "algorithm" as such.

Comment: That's simply not what I asked. It's irrelevant and OT to my question. Was there something wrong with my attitude or interactions? Obviously I had no demeanor of "Wow I want to win this competition please I'll try my best" - at the time I was clearly just wanting to do my best because I cared so much for the network's future.

Comment: from what you describe, you're one of the top, most active users over there. If I was picking mods, that alone would make a solid reason _against_ you. It is important for such users to have a free ride and let them shape site in their own, _individually_ picked way. Mods just have their hands tied too much for that. This is especially important in beta, while site is small and individual contribution weights much more but even after graduation, I would recommend you think twice about it if you ever decide to nominate for elections

Comment: That's interesting to think about, that if I hadn't been so active I would have been more eligible, at least in terms of consideration. Seems stupid to me.

Answer (score 27):

It's not what you could call an algorithm. I *wish* it could be made that simple.

When we start the process of identifying people within a new community with the qualifications needed to *lead* that community, potentially for several years until an actual election is held, we often come up with more awesome people than available positions. It's then a process of reaching out to everyone, and making a decision.

We *definitely* listen to the community in the way that they vote on the nomination thread, but it has to be our call. You should *most decidedly not* feel at all bad about not being selected. It's a very hard choice. In the end, we want a team that:

- Has a topic expert, a generalist in the field, someone that can make good calls when it comes to the quality of contributions the site receives.
- Has a network expert, someone that really understands how our software works, someone that can help new users learn the features and the ropes, someone that's familiar with tagging and the other nooks and crannies that communities need to build.
- (Ideally) has someone that's pretty new to our platform, someone that is going to question things when the way we're doing something seems a little silly.

This isn't always possible, but it's the (ideal) balanced team.

We have three slots for a couple of good reasons, one being redundancy and the other of course diversity. Three means there's a tie-breaker if one is needed, and several sets of hands make light work.

***Every single time I've appointed the first round of pro-tem moderators on a site, I've ended up wishing there was a fourth slot.***

Here, you have these people — these *awesome* people — and they want nothing more than to give you even more of their time happily, and commit to doing so for the long haul. Why oh *why* can't we just give them the tools they're asking for and let them get down to business?

There can't be a fourth slot, or there'd need to be a fifth slot, too. When you get to a team of that size, you risk a certain level of consistency in how things are handled on the site that comes from a smaller, tighter team. This sort of consistency is pretty critical in the early days, because how a new community is going to do a great number of things is still relatively up in the air.

No, your rep on Stack Overflow isn't really an influencing factor in if you are or aren't selected. Honestly, meta participation, initiative, how well you communicate, how much you comment, and a bunch of other things are far more important than how much rep you have on some other site.

Yet, so many times, ***all*** of the potential candidates are *equally* good at all of these things. *Aaaaaaggggghhhh!*

***Not being selected in no way means that you lack any of these things***, and it also doesn't mean that someone that *was* selected is somehow technically better for the position than you would have been.

All it means is that a human being on the community team absorbed as *much* about each person that they possibly could, spent *quite a while* considering the possibilities, and put together the most balanced team that they possibly could - sometimes going on a bit of intuition to boot.

You'd have made a fine moderator on Startups. You might yet - remember - we hold democratic moderator elections once a site graduates. I'd love to see you jump into other topics on Area 51 that interest you, and get involved in even more new communities if you have the time.

Don't take it personally, it's a very tough call and a *very* manual process.

Comment: I just feel like the moderator must have done a poor job. I had the highest quality edits, the most helpful (and unnecessarily nice) comments. The most responsible ethic and the most professional form of communication (unlike what you're reading here). Like I said in my other post - is it really a fair system? To let one person "judge" the presence of these qualifying attributes? By their own observations? I'm sure there's too much content to observe, so why *potentially* only let one moderator handle it? It still errs me that gold badges are given for this privy-natured selection.

Comment: The other problem I have with this is that you call an algorithm simple. That seems very fishy to me ;)

Comment: @jdero If we _could_ make it so that the burden of the selection process is offloaded to something that is intrinsically _more_ likely to do a better job than a seasoned community manager - it would _indeed_ be much simpler for said community managers :) Nothing fishy intended. If you have a problem with the conduct of a moderator on your site, you should contact us directly.

Comment: For starters, what's the point of having a community moderator select some network-specific pro-temp moderators in the first place? Why not use strict community-common qualifications to filter out those who are not fit for the position, specifically have community moderators go through the remaining list and DQ the ones who aren't fit, and let it just go straight to a vote?

Comment: My point being - it seems very *anti stack exchange* to put this much power and reward (excuse the word, but it's kind of what gold badges are made for) into the hands of a *potentially small* few? Seems more like an autocracy in this situation. Regardless of whether my moderator did his or her job correctly (all respect to them), *what if* they simply don't care as much as the actual community? I never saw our moderator do any edits, reviews, or anything besides a few meta posts. Did they enable ghost mode? :-)

Comment: @jdero We're not appointed or elected moderators, we're _Stack Exchange Employees_, it's our job to care and make what we feel is the best possible call for young sites. As we've launched well over a hundred, we're pretty good at selecting well balanced teams. There are just way too many things undecided about a site to hold a formal election that early, or we definitely would. The community is just too small to make a representative decision that could potentially last years. Elections take place when actual representation by the community is meaningful, or, much more than 40 - 50 folks.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I see a lot of merit in your post. Not to beat a dead horse, but how do you know it's *a good system* as opposed to something else? What about all the sites that don't make it past open beta? I get that the model for stackexchange pursues success and will make many successful networks, but how is this model tested against its alternatives if we just "assume it to be a good one?" I guess I'm just wondering if other methods have been pursued.

Comment: @jdero Even though we've launched a _bunch_ of sites, there's still some uncharted waters. Sites that have failed in private or public beta did so because they just didn't have enough interested people behind them, we've never had a case of a site folding due to inept or excessive moderation. The only thing that happens from time to time is someone accepting an appointment, and then some kind of life changing event that leaves them without the time to actually do it. But, well, that's extremely hard to predict. Honestly, I think our _entire_ site creation process is due for a checkup (cont)

Comment: (continued) as a _whole_. I think we're too slow to launch new sites (or striking while the iron is at the hottest), and I think there should be more stuff folks can do while they wait a (shorter) length of time to see if an idea gains enough interest to launch. And you know, from that - there might be a bit more to go on regarding the best potential mod candidates. As we have it now, we're honestly using everything we can to go on, and it really _does_ take a human being to make the decision. For that to change, or us to have the room to try something else, we'd have to make more changes.

Answer (score 9):

There is no algorithm, pro-tempore mods are individually chosen by the SE community managers. There are some general guidelines, but no hard rules.

My impression is not that SE excludes users because they aren't active on many other sites. There are plenty of cases where users were chosen that didn't have much or no experience with the SE network prior to the new beta site.

I wouldn't say that experience with other SE sites doesn't matter, if all three moderators are completely new I'd expect some more difficulty adjusting than usual. It is useful in my opinion to have at least one moderator that is reasonably familiar with the SE system, but that shouldn't disqualify good candidates without that experience.

There are often multiple good candidates, and in the end the decision is likely to come down to a subjective judgment of the candidates based on their visible history on the site. I have quite a lot of experience interacting with the SE community team as a moderator, and I tend to trust their judgement in this. I don't think any objective measurements would improve the process, reputation and activity alone don't tell you if a user would be a good moderator.

I also don't think the whole process should be more transparent, in many cases it would not be productive to tell the users not chosen why they weren't chosen.

You shouldn't see it as a slight if you're not chosen, there are often many good candidates, but almost always only three positions open.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Is it really fair to put this decision in the hands of one person? Just a follow up question I suppose.

Comment: @jdero The fair process comes after graduation, then moderators are elected democratically by the community.

Comment: @jdero the decision is not in the hands of one person. There are a number of community managers and there *will* be discussions about who to appoint.

Comment: I wish I knew that beforehand. This is why I wasn't selected ;)

Comment: @ChrisF I've clarified that a bit, we actually don't know how many are involved in each decision, but you're right that they are likely discussing this internally from what we know.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to give out gold badges for being a hand-picked person by *potentially* one moderator? It still errs me. Why not silver?

Comment: @jdero Yes, it's a good idea to give out gold badges for pro-tem mods. Most sites stay in beta for months or even years; they pro-tem mods put in a lot of time and effort and deserved to be recognized for that.

Comment: I'm clearly not disregarding their hard work, and I feel I'm being bombarded with irrelevant data to try and pull sympathy out of my actual concern. The point is the checks and balances behind the opportunity. I appreciate and congratulate anyone promoted as a pro tempore mod.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought (hoped) that your reputation on another site in the network wasn't taken into account.

However, don't forget that with 4 nominations and only 3 positions to fill *someone* will have to have lost. I'm not privy (nor would I expect to be) to the discussions that went on in choosing the moderators, but you could have "lost" by the smallest of margins. Unless one of the team weighs in we'll never know - nor would I expect to know why one person was chosen over someone else. Some things are better left private.

Comment: My point being - why not just be transparent or opaque? Nobody likes a translucent set of rules.